# Showing the Date in correct format in a Smartgwt project

Tags: date, smartgwt, listgrid

I am getting a date from JSON in the following format `22 07 2014 12:04:12`. 
This is the code I have written:

```
field.setCellFormatter(new CellFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String format(Object arg0, ListGridRecord arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        final DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd MM yyyy hh:mm");
        final Date date = (Date) arg0;

            arg1.setAttribute(name, date);
            return fmt.format(date);
});
```

where `field` is the Date field in ListGrid.
But this displays a blank field in the ListGrid. I can't figure out a way to show it in the following format:
`22 Jul 2014 00:04`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/RestDataSource.html), the server must send dates with the following format:

> dateField: "2007-04-22"
>
> timeField: "11:07:13"
>
> dateTimeField: "2007-04-22T11:07:13"
>
> dateTimeField: "2007-04-22T11:07:13.582"

You can achieve that with this snippet:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
sdf.format(myDate);
```

Then, in the client side, you can format the date with SmartGWT:

```
myListGridField.setDateFormatter(DateDisplayFormat.TOEUROPEANSHORTDATETIME);
```